# Como ler o arquivo wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Bom dia pessoal, estou produzindo um app android que seja capaz de gerar um backup em **txt** das configurações de redes salvas em um dispositivo android, até então sei que é necessário ler os parâmetros do arquivo *wpa_supplicant* que fica em uma pasta do sistema. A pergunta é:

É possível ler esse arquivo sem o meu app ter que ter permissão de **root**? Se sim, como posso proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom... aparentemente não é possível ler os perfis de rede salvo no dispositivo a menos que o mesmo esteja enraizado (**root**), caso contrário seria um problema de segurança. A resolução do problema é criar um aplicativo de "**chaveiro**" onde o próprio usuário fornece as informações do perfil das redes e essas informações ficam salvas em um banco de dados e posteriormente ao importar o backup adicionar ao *supplicant* os perfis através dos métodos da classe *WifiManager* ([https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html))

Nesse caso vou fechar o tópico, quem conhecer alguma alternativa pode comentar.